# How is a process descriptor initlialized

Tags: linux, process, fork

How and when is the elements of 'task_struct' (process descriptor) initalized. Are they get initlized automatically after the fork() system call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "task_struct" gets initialized by the kernel once fork() system gets completed for the child process.

When program calls fork() system calls, kernel starts executing its internal main routine "do_fork". You can find the complete source code(fork.c) [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13.5/kernel/fork.c)

```
long do_fork(unsigned long clone_flags,
unsigned long stack_start,
struct pt_regs *regs,
unsigned long stack_size,
int __user *parent_tidptr,
int __user *child_tidptr)
```

Internally "do_fork" does executes the "copy_process" routine which is responsible for the initializing the **"task_struct"** of the child process. Its prototype has been defined as

```
static struct task_struct *copy_process(unsigned long clone_flags,
                                       unsigned long stack_start,
                                        unsigned long stack_size,
                                        int __user *child_tidptr,
                                        struct pid *pid,
                                        int trace)
```

It basically make a copy of the old task_struct and starts updating various attributes in it. So once fork() system calls gets completed, there would be a new "task_sturct" for the child process which stores all important information about a process which gets used by kernel at the various times while executing the process.

Comment: thanks a lot,i have one more silly doubt ..what if the there is no fork() call. Suppose just a simple program then how will task_struct gets initialized.

Comment: @tunu: All processes/program would start executing the when parent process calls fork() system call. fork() is the only way to start the all processes in linux/unix except the init process(PID = 0).For example when you type command(./a.out) on your shell command prompt,shell process(parent) internally does call fork() for ./a.out and that how program starts execution. So task_struct would always would be initialized and maintained for a each process.